# Ordering model records in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using on console:

```
User.all(:order => "created_at ASC")
```

by replacing Client with my Model User
from [Rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html), but its giving me this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Take a look at your URL, that guide is for Rails v2.3.11 and according to your tags, you are either using Rails 3 or Rails 4.

Comment: thanks I didn't notice it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `ActiveRecord#order` for this goal:

```
User.order("created_at ASC")
```

or just:

```
User.order(:created_at)
```

in your case.

`ActiveRecord#all` method not expects any arguments.